# Check if item is in a list (Lisp)

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

What's a simple way to check if an item is in a list?

Something like

```
(in item list)
```

might return `true` if `item=1` and `list=(5 9 1 2)` and `false` if `item=7`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Common Lisp**

`FIND` is not a good idea:

```
> (find nil '(nil nil))
NIL
```

Above would mean that `NIL` is not in the list `(NIL NIL)` - which is wrong.

The purpose of `FIND` is not to check for membership, but to find an element, which satisfies a test (in the above example the test function is the usual default `EQL`). `FIND` returns such an element.

Use `MEMBER`:

```
> (member nil '(nil nil))
(NIL NIL)  ; everything non-NIL is true
```

or `POSITION`:

```
> (numberp (position nil '()))
NIL
```

Answer (score 22):

**Use `MEMBER` to test whether an item is in a list:**

```
(member 1 '(5 9 1 2))  ; (1 2)
```

Unlike `FIND`, it is also able to test whether `NIL` is in the list.

Comment: I do not really like this advise as it is. member returns the list from the position on where the element is found. The question asks for something like a predicate, returning either `T` or `NIL`. Hence I suggest this answer should be wrapped in an `if` and all that defined as the function anyone reading this page is looking for: `(defun contains (item sequence) (if (member item sequence) T NIL))`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `find`:

```
(find 1 '(5 9 1 2)) ; 1
(find 7 '(5 9 1 2)) ; nil
```

Consider using `:test` argument:

```
(find "a" '("a" "b") :test #'equal)
```

Comment: (find nil '(nil nil)) -> nil